# Python threading Queue is very slow while passing queue reference

Tags: python, multithreading, theano, deep-learning

I'm building a Deeplearning model which optimizes using SGD. I have a python threading queue and I hold at a time 10 minibatches inside it. When I call the gradient descent step function, I pop out one minibatch and send it to it. But it takes a long time, and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to pass the reference of the queue to the function. The following are the small snippets of code which shows how I do it. The overhead being almost 100 times slower than other operations.

```
class DataLoaderThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__():
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
       ***code block not mentioned, not important***
            if self.ae:
                self.queue.put(train_features1)
            else:
                self.queue.put(train_features1)

#####################################################################
the main function:
def main():
        start1=time.time()
        **q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=10)**
        data_loader = DataLoaderThread(q, data_file_list, batch_size,         is_training=(not test), ae=(not is_full_model))

        data_loader.daemon = True
        data_loader.start()
        print 'time for dataloader', (time.time() - start1)
        **do_training(q, numbertotal_samples, batch_size, weights_share)**
        data_loader.terminate()
        data_loader.join()
    return 0
###############################################
the training function:
**def do_training**(**data_q**,batch_size, weights_share):

    model = gatedAE.FactoredGatedAutoencoder(**necessary args**)
    learningrate = 0.00005 
    trainer = GraddescentMinibatch(model, batch_size, learningrate)
    print 'time for first portion of do training', (time.time() - start_train)

    try:
        while True:
            # TRAIN MODEL
            **cost=trainer.step(data_q)**
            loss+= cost
            print 'cost_at_evry_batch',cost
            epoch += 1
            if epoch % progress_report == 0:
                loss /= progress_report
                print '%d\t%g' % (epoch, loss)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                loss = 0

##############################################
Finally just the step function from gradient descent:
 **def step**(self,data_q):
        time_step=time.time()
        **val=data_q.get()
        print 'time outside set_sharedval in step :', (time.time() - time_step)**
        time_sharedval=time.time()
        cost=self.set_shareddata(val)
        print 'time inside sharedval in step :', (time.time() - time_sharedval)
        #cost = (1.0-1.0/stepcount)*cost + (1.0/stepcount)*self._updateincs(np.asarray(val))
        #ipdb.set_trace()
        self._trainmodel(0)
        self.model.normalizefilters()
        return cost
########################################################################
```

The  print 'time outside set_sharedval in step :', (time.time() - time_step) statement from the step function outputs 200 seconds required to do this part of the code, which really has nothing except loading the queue and popping a value from it makes me think there's something wrong with how I construct and pass the data loader. ALL the necessary code flow in between functions are in bolds for easy reading.

Comment: There's *far* too much code here. Please cut it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Any good DanielRoseman, would you know why is this happening? As far as I have understood the data_q.get_value() seems to be slow but no clue why.

Comment: Could it have something to do with Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)? Python interpreter can't execute more than 1 python op in parallel, so each thread has to wait until GIL is released

Comment: Yes it is for GIL. Is there any workaround?